# Visual Studio place marks into code

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, comments, bookmarks, add-on

I wonder I can create marks in my code to group code interventions that refers on same tasks.

Let me explain by example: I have a bug-fixing task that involves to modify 3 different files (let's say they're an aspx, an aspx.cs and a class). I'd love to mark each edit with a comment like `//fix FOO-BAR - that's my fix for foo-bar`. Off course I already can do it by write down a tag every time, but I guess there will be a tool/plugin/built-in feature for visual studio to manage it in an automatic and fashon way

Thanks

Comment: What kind of source control system are you using?

Comment: i'm using git. I already use commits for documenting changes, but having them right away in the code I think is faster and brighter.
Did you have anything else in mind?

Comment: No, I was just thinking that you might be missing the point of modern source control systems as git or svn to commit several related file changes as one change. With the annotate feature you can very quickly find the ticket to the change. You should, however, add the ticket number to the commit message.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd normally do is add a check-in comment to the files you're checking into source control. If you're using something like TFS you can use the [Annotate feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx) to see which lines were changed by who and this will also show you the change comment.
[image: Annotate screenshot]

[CodeLens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx), a new Visual Studio Ultimate feature will also show the changed made to each method together with the associated change comment.
[image: CodeLens Changes feature]

The advantage of using the Source Control system to record these comments is that your code remains clean and that you can have multiple changes to the same line, each with their own comment. In-lining these into the code would create an unreadable mess.

Other source control systems, like Git and Subversion offer similar features to Annotate. Visual Studio 2013 update 2 is likely going to feature CodeLens support for Git as well.

If you're looking for a tool to retroactively add review comments to the code, the new [TFS Web Access lightweight review](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/11/01/collaborative-commenting.aspx) system allows you to add review comments to existing code. Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 adds CodeLens integration with the Code Review system as well.

[image: Lightweight Code Commenting]

Due to the fact that these systems allow your code to remain clean, and still have comments on your changes and code reviews, I'd recommend against trying to find a tool that drops all kinds of markers in your actual code. There's better ways to accomplish the same thing.